# Convert Animated Jquery Side Nav to Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help converting a Jquery side navigation menu into Vanilla JS. I'm a beginner with JS and have no idea how to accomplish this. Also any advice on animating the burger icon to transform into an X when clicked? Thank you. Any help is appreciated

```css
/**********************
  ****NAVIGATION****
**********************/
#sidebar{
 background: #151718;
 width: 12.500em;
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: -12.500em;
 top: 0px;
 transition: left 0.3s linear;
}

#sidebar.visible{
 left: 0.000em;
}

nav{
 text-align: center;
}

ul{
 margin: 0.000em;
 padding: 0.000em;
}

ul li{
 list-style: none;
}

ul li a{
 background: #1c1e1f;
 color: #ccc;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
 display: block;
 width: 11.250em;
 padding: 0.625em;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase
}
 

ul li a:hover{
 color: #4876FF; 
}

#sidebar-btn{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 1.563em;
 height: 1.250em;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 1.250em; 
 position: absolute;
 top: 0.000em;
 right: -3.750em;
}

#sidebar-btn span{
 height: 0.063em;
 background: #282828;
 margin-bottom: 0.313em;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Responsive Side Nav</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/normalize.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style.css"
</head>
<body>
 
  <div id="sidebar">
  
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 
 <div id="sidebar-btn">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
    <span></span>
 </div>
 </div>
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>
   
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
     $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible');
    });
   });
   
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute `window.onload = function(){}` for `$(document).ready()`; `.addEventListener("click", function() {})` for `.click(function() {})`; `document.getElementById()` for `jQuery()`; `Element.classList.toggle()` for `.toggleClass()`

```css
/**********************
  ****NAVIGATION****
**********************/

#sidebar {
  background: #151718;
  width: 12.500em;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -12.500em;
  top: 0px;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}

#sidebar.visible {
  left: 0.000em;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0.000em;
  padding: 0.000em;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  background: #1c1e1f;
  color: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
  display: block;
  width: 11.250em;
  padding: 0.625em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #4876FF;
}

#sidebar-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1.563em;
  height: 1.250em;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 1.250em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.000em;
  right: -3.750em;
}

#sidebar-btn span {
  height: 0.063em;
  background: #282828;
  margin-bottom: 0.313em;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Responsive Side Nav</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="sidebar">

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div id="sidebar-btn">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('sidebar-btn')
        .addEventListener("click", function() {
          document.getElementById('sidebar')
          .classList.toggle('visible');
        });
      };
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```