# Converting Jquery sidenav into vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jquery, nav

I'm pretty familiar with jquery but im trying to learn vanilla js. How would I go about converting this jquery snippet into vanilla JS?

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() { // DOM Ready

    // Toggle navigation
    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      // If sidebar is visible:
      if ($('body').hasClass('show-nav')) {
        // Hide sidebar
        $('body').removeClass('show-nav');
      } else { // If sidebar is hidden:
        $('body').addClass('show-nav');
        // Display sidebar
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: document ready -> [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). `$('#nav-toggle')` -> `document.getElementById()`. `.click` -> `addEventListener`. `hasClass` / `removeClass` / `addClass` -> [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: What have you tried? If we do the work for you, how are you learning? Apparently you didn't learn anything the last time you asked a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592157/convert-animated-jquery-side-nav-to-vanilla-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to convert jquery code to javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978799/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-jquery-code-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the vanilla js version**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById('nav-toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");

      var body = document.querySelector('body');
      // If sidebar is visible:
      if (body.classList.contains('show-nav')) {
        // Hide sidebar
        body.classList.remove('show-nav');
      } else { // If sidebar is hidden:
        body.classList.add('show-nav');
        // Display sidebar
      }
    });
});
```

## Resources

- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`Document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Comment: FYI, you're missing the _"document ready"_ part

Comment: `var body = document.querySelector('body');` ... or just `var body = document.body;`

Comment: no, not even with IIFE is it same as `$(function() { // DOM Ready`

Comment: @phil some people downvote to discourage answers on lazy questions

Comment: The whole _"if has class, remove else add class"_ can be simplified to `document.body.classList.toggle('show-nav')`

Comment: @jmoerdyk seems misguided. Downvote the question, not the answer especially if there's nothing technically wrong with it

Comment: @Ele eh, just a suggestion

Comment: @Phil meh, it's their vote to waste.  But I kind of agree that we shouldn't encourage lazy posters